# Layover in Europe to the US - allowed?

Tags: usa, layovers, covid-19

Many people have asked questions on this site regarding the rules for layovers, with no definitive answers. The rules are constantly in flux and it is very difficult to get a clear answer from government websites.

I would like to buy a plane ticket for my mother-in-law (who has a visa) from Ukraine to the US. Most available flights have at least one layover in Europe. My understanding is that EU countries (minus some special cases and US citizens) are currently banned from travel to the US.

**If we buy a ticket with a layover in, say, Switzerland, can there be a problem? Is this allowed under current rules?**

Comment: Flying via Turkey is your best bet. Just need a COVID test and you're good to go.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

There is a problem. Foreigners who have been physically present in Mainland China, Iran, the Schengen Area, the UK, Ireland, Brazil, or South Africa in the previous 14 days are [currently banned from entry to the US](https://www.whitehouse.gov/briefing-room/presidential-actions/2021/01/25/proclamation-on-the-suspension-of-entry-as-immigrants-and-non-immigrants-of-certain-additional-persons-who-pose-a-risk-of-transmitting-coronavirus-disease/)* (with some exceptions). Switzerland is in the Schengen Area. Transiting there would involve being "physically present" there, and would thus make you inadmissible to the US for 14 days.

- the original ban was [from March 2020, by President Trump](https://www.schengenvisainfo.com/news/us-visa-esta-holders-outside-eu-cannot-transit-schengen-on-their-way-to-us/); the ban was renewed by President Biden in January 2021, link above.

From the [comments](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/163330/layover-in-europe-to-the-us-allowed#comment410837_163331), it confirms this in practice:

> I'm a resident of Ukraine, we had Ukrainian friends who were unable to fly through AMS to the US, but were able to fly through Istanbul without an issue. I'd recommend flying through Istanbul (**KLM denied boarding at the check in counter at KBP airport**)

emphasis mine.

Comment: But people having been in Ukraine would be allowed on a direct flight? Covid numbers seem as bad to me as the Schengen area (and much worse than Mainland China)

Comment: @lalala Regulations and law are sometimes inconsistent, inaccurate, or wrong.

Comment: @lalala Between the visa requirement for Ukrainian citizens and the lack of direct flights, that might be a non-issue, whereas banning travel from Schengen area and the UK would have a significant effect on the number of people entering the US. It also seems the list isn't updated very frequently : the last update was in January (when the number of cases was going apparently down in Ukraine while it was increasing in the countries listed), Chinas has remained on the list since early 2020 even as official figures suggest the outbreak is largely under control there.

Comment: She might be able to fly from Ukraine to Russia, and from Russia to the US, though, since Russia isn't on that list.

Comment: Does that also apply to transiting via an airside transit zone?

Comment: @nick012000 As far as I know, there are no direct flights between Ukraine and Russia at the moment. The options are Belavia with a layover in Belarus (expensive), or a ~24 hr train/bus ride.

Comment: @WhatHiFi Huh. Is the Ukrainian government still that angry of the annexation of Crimea, or is that a Covid thing? Ukraine and Russia are right next to each other, so it's sort of surprising to me that you can't fly from one to the other.

Comment: @nick012000 The fact that the two countries are basically in a state of war with each other over eastern Ukraine might be playing a role here...

Comment: I'm a resident of Ukraine, we had Ukrainian friends who were unable to fly through AMS to the US, but were able to fly through Istanbul without an issue. I'd recommend flying through Istanbul (KLM denied boarding at the check in counter at KBP airport)