# Travel to USA as a fully-vaccinated [ AstraZeneca ] person

Tags: international-travel, covid-19

I plan to travel to New York next month from Germany. I am a Turkish citizen.

[CDC guidelines](https://www.cdc.gov/coronavirus/2019-ncov/travelers/international-travel-during-covid19.html) say that fully-vaccinated people **do NOT** have to quarantine upon arrival, with a note at the bottom of the page:

> *This guidance applies to COVID-19 vaccines currently authorized for emergency use by the Food and Drug Administration: Pfizer-BioNTech, Moderna, and Johnson and Johnson (J&J)/Janssen COVID-19 vaccines. This guidance can also be applied to COVID-19 vaccines that have been authorized for emergency use by the World Health Organization (e.g. AstraZeneca/Oxford).

Since the AstraZeneca vaccine is authorized by the WHO, I assume I also don't have to quarantine upon my arrival.

Would my assumption be correct?

Thank you.

Comment: Do you meet any of the exceptions listed in [this proclamation](https://www.whitehouse.gov/briefing-room/presidential-actions/2021/01/25/proclamation-on-the-suspension-of-entry-as-immigrants-and-non-immigrants-of-certain-additional-persons-who-pose-a-risk-of-transmitting-coronavirus-disease/)? Other than those exceptions, people who have been in the Schengen Zone (e.g. Germany) in the last 14 days are not currently permitted to enter the US regardless of vaccination status.

Comment: @ChrisH I don't think so. I am just a regular Joe who wants to attend some NBA playoff games. But I am not sure that proclamation applies to fully vaccinated people, couldn't find anything about that. Also, CDC guidelines do not mention it.

Comment: @user1955276: The entry ban does not have any exceptions for vaccinated people.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Layover in Europe to the US - allowed?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/163330/layover-in-europe-to-the-us-allowed) especially this https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/163330/layover-in-europe-to-the-us-allowed#comment410837_163331 if you do not live in Germany, then just fly from Istanbul to New York straight.

Comment: The flight is [operational](https://flightaware.com/live/flight/THY6291/history/20210521/0653Z/LTBA/KJFK) as of May 21, 2021.